# vue v-bind style - smooth changes, not instantly

Tags: css, vue.js

I use "vuex-module-decorators" and dynamically determine the style  in this getter:

`<div class="viewport":style="viewportStyleVars">...</div>`

```
get viewportStyleVars() {
      const tx = -this.viewportRect.x;
      const ty = -this.viewportRect.y;
      return {
        '--translate-x': `${tx}px`,
        '--translate-y': `${ty}px`,
      }
    }
```

How to make change happen smoothly, not instantly?
I would be grateful for the hints, I am not familiar with the animation.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add transition in CSS to the div with class `.viewport` something like:

```
.viewport{
  transition: all 1s linear;
}
```

The **1s** in the transition, is the time, that the action will take, you can tweak this value to something smaller, like 0.1s, if that suits you better.